# Como exibo atributos de um objeto armazenado em um vetor?

Tags: java, array, método, objetos, atributos

Estou fazendo um trabalho que consiste num imobiliária fictícia. Neste programa existe uma classe chamada principal onde recebe Imovel (Classe) e armazena os imoveis em um vetor, uma classe Imobiliaria que tem metodo de cadastrar os imoveis, uma superclasse Imovel e outras 4 classes que são os tipos de Imovel (Terreno, SalaComercial, Casa e Apartamento) cada uma dessas 4 classes possui um @override de Imovel para exibir seus atributos.
segue como eu realizei o armazenamento dos imoveis:

```
Imovel[] imoveis; // cria vetor de imoveis do tipo Imovel (SuperClasse)

//Pega o imovel e coloca no dito array
public void setImovelArray(Imovel imv) {
        imoveis[b] = imv;
        b++;
        System.out.println("Imóvel guardado sob ID:"+b);
    }
```

Partido da logica onde a classe Imobiliaria possui a função cadastrar imovel e a classe Principal a função de armazenar no array. Onde e como eu chamo uma função para buscar no array um imovel especifico (ex pelo atributo dono existente em todos os imoveis) e chamar sua respectiva função exibirDetalhes(); existente em cada instância de imovel?

Qualquer informação adicional pode solicitar ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não manjo muito de java. Mas todos os tipos de imoveis onde vc quer buscar os dados herdam da classe imóvel.

Você pode fazer  um método nela passando os atributos que vc pode querer buscar e caso não possua por padrão vc seta nulo.

Na implementação dessa classe vc percorre o array buscando o valor que veio passado no parametro.

E por fim na principal vc chama essa implementação para todos os tipos de imoveis que vc precisa.

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma :D